# RegEx to Strip text from middle of URL

Tags: regex

I have a client that's moving her site from Blogger to a Wordpress blog.  I put some code in Blogger to redirect visitors to the right Wordpress post/page.  So when Blogger redirects a post, it comes through as **www.domain.com/?bloggerURL=/yyyy/mm/the-post-slug.html**

With this Regex, I'm successfully returning the proper Wordpress URL: **www.domain.com/yyyy/mm/the-post-slug** (with "?bloggerURL=/" and ".html" removed)

```
^\?bloggerURL=/(.*)\.html$
```

Blogger Pages get redirected like **www.domain.com/?bloggerURL=/p/the-page-slug.html**  I tried just adding the /p to the Regex to strip out this case also, but it's not working.

```
^\?bloggerURL=/p/(.*)\.html$
```

For instance, **www.domain.com/?bloggerURL=/p/about.html** should be redirected to **www.domain.com/about**, but the URL is remaining as **www.domain.com/?bloggerURL=/p/about.html**

I'm probably missing something simple to get it to pick up the first part of the string and remove it.  Is there something I need to add/remove to get that case working?

Comment: Why don't you catch it as a querystring and treat it there?

Comment: Well, it's not actually going in an .htaccess file.  She moved to WP Engine which uses their own redirect system.  So I'm having to do it in a screen like this: http://www.scottkustes.com/images/redirect.png  Is it something I could do in the "match args" field?

Comment: I ran the regular expression that isn't working through Regex Coach and it says that it matches.  Yet the redirect isn't working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the code that does the substitution & redirect?

Comment: Hey Steve,
I didn't write them in .htaccess since my client uses WP-Engine and they have a Redirect Rules area instead of .htaccess.  The regexes are:

    ^\?bloggerURL=/(.*)\.html$ redirects to /$1, 
    ^\?bloggerURL=/p/(.*)\.html$ redirects to /about, 
    and (.*)\.html$ redirects to /$1.

The bloggerURL with "/p" in it is for pages on Blogger.  I just sent them all to her About page.  The actual redirect you use will depend on your permalink setup.

Answer (score 0):

Just going through old, unanswered questions... hopefully you've solved this one, but in case not, the only problem I see with the regex is the non-escaped slashes. I think you would need to use:

```
^\?bloggerURL=\/p\/(.*)\.html$
```

Hope this might help someone else.